# Is there any new book for new iPhone sdk for intermediate or Advance learners

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any books for intermediate and advance learners on iphone new things.

Please suggest.

Thank you,

Madan Mohan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended iOS books after beginner´s books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692714/recommended-ios-books-after-beginners-books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        This one is good:

        "iPhone Advanced Projects" by Appress 
        and here is its link 
http://www.easy-share.com/1908447683/Apress.iPhone.Advanced.Projects.Oct.2009.rar
```